# How to do element extraction in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have placeholder with any web page url. It should extract the elements when i click on button. I have to show elements and xpath values in my page. How can i do that? Please help me.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? It's still unclear for me of what you're asking.

Comment: yeah. I added sample image. let's say i given url in top. when i click on extract button. It should show the actions and buttons all those elements and xpath values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is what you want, but if you need to display every element's XPath, here is my solution:

```
function buildDom(text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = text;
  return div.firstChild;
}

function fetchAttrs(node) { // getting attributes object for element
  return node && Array.prototype.reduce.call(node.attributes, function(list, attribute) {
    list[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    return list;
  }, {}) || {};
};

function traverseElement(element, argPrefix = "") {
  if (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    return; // skipping text elements

  var attrs = fetchAttrs(element)
  var prefix = argPrefix + "/" + element.tagName; // build element path
  if (Object.keys(attrs).length !== 0){
    prefix += "[" + Object.keys(attrs).map((value, index) => {
      return "@" + value + ' = "' + attrs[value] + '"'
    }).join(" and ") + "]" // append arguments
  }

  console.log(prefix);

  var children = element.childNodes // iterating over children
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    traverseElement(children[i], prefix)
  }
}

var url = "https://icanhazip.com/" // URL to load

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // when loaded
    var dom = buildDom(this.responseText); // build a DOM tree from a response string
    traverseElement(dom) // and traverse it
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true); 
xhttp.send(); // loading needed website
```

Comment: Thanks. where can i pass web page url

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @serge1peshcoff,
I am not able to bind the DOM and not able to get the firstNodeValue. dom response is empty object .

Comment: okay, what is `this.responseText` after loading data? and was the request successful?

Comment: yeah. I am getting responseText and request is successful. Can i paste responseText here?

Comment: it won't fit into one comment, you can try pasting it into Github Gist, for example, and post it here. And are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is my responsetext file.

Just i posted in my GIT repo 

https://github.com/Sandeepvedam/element-extraction-javascript/blob/master/response.txt

Comment: Try using another HTML, maybe this one is invalid

Comment: I did not see any error in html file. I am not getting firstChild for all web urls .Are you able to run that previously?

Comment: Oh.. damn. Even i did not see any issue in debugging. Can you please help in GIT repo

Comment: Hi @serge1peshcoff 

your logic saved me. Thank you very much for your time. I did it. I will update it on GIT repo soon.

Comment: Hi, Will you check it once? https://github.com/Sandeepvedam/element-extraction-javascript

Comment: Hi @serge       
How can i highlight related elements in web page if i click on xpath values.

Please help me. Thanks for your help